# How probabilities and predictions are calculated in logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have these values of y and x:

```
y  x
0  3
0  4
0  7
1  8
1  11
0  14
1  15
1  16
1  17
```

I want to calculate prediction for values 9 and 20 using logistic regression. But I don't understand how. I know that it can be calculated like this: $$P(y_{i} = 1) = P(y_{i} \geq 0) = P(\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i} + \varepsilon_{i} \geq 0) =  P(\varepsilon_{i} \leq \beta_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}) = F(\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}) = \frac{e^{\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}}}{1+e^{\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}}}$$ But I don't understand how coefficients $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$ are calculated.

I calculated probabilities using python and sklearn library and it says that the probability for x=5 to be 0 is 0.82 and probability for x=20 to be 1 is 0.97

How it is calculated? Could you break down prediction for values 5 and 20 using my given dataset?

Comment: It seems like you know how the probabilities are computed once you have the model parameters, but are asking how to solve for the model parameters. There is no closed form solution, so they are solved for using algorithms like gradient descent. Here's a related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/949/when-is-logistic-regression-solved-in-closed-form

Comment: @Joe still don't get it. how coefficients are calculated? what is a formula? could you explain how probability is calculated?

Comment: You have the formula for the probability in your post. What part of the formula that you wrote don't you understand?  As for determining the coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, you have to let the computer do that, by minimizing an error function using an algorithm like gradient descent (or some other optimization algorithm).